# For CVD diamond in a reaction chamber why does a lower temperature lead to a greater height value/thickness

Tags: materials

I've learned that for CVD ([chemical vapor deposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_vapor_deposition) ) crystals in a reaction chamber, the greater the temperature the smaller the growth rate so the crystals have a smaller height. I know at lower temperatures the growth rate is faster and this is something to do with the balance between etching and growth rate but I'm not sure why this happens. Also, we have to compare the height at different times and why there is a fluctuation as you leave it in the reaction chamber up to an hour (3 min, 10 mins, 20 mins, 40 mins and 60 mins)

Also we have learned that at larger temperatures it is a slower reaction in the reaction chamber, however I am not sure why it is slower so why the grain size is larger.

Comment: Huh, homework about making of diamonds? Some people are more lucky ;)